# How to insert data from bean to the database in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I'm having user class for which contains user data like

user.java

```
@Table(name="user");
@Column(name="userid")
public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}//setter and getter for username,password and mobile no.
```

I'm having signup page where I have to enter some of above details,after successful login whatever the response i m getting that again storing to this user object but now I want to insert it into the database.this is my

userdao.java

```
package com.xyz.dao;

import com.xyz.model.User;

public class UserDao {
    public interface UserDAO {
        public void insert(User user);
    }
}
```

and this is my

```
import com.xyz.dao.UserDao.UserDAO;
import com.xyz.model.User;

public class UserJdbcImpl implements UserDAO {
    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void insert(User user) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        String sql = "INSERT INTO user " +
                "(userMobile,userEmail ) VALUES (?, ?)";

        try {
            conn = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            //conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            System.out.println("connecting..");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(1, user.getUserMobile());
            ps.setString(2, user.getUserEmail());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("connection failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            return conn;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

As I'm going for authentication in the login page I'm using spring-security.xml and this is my spring-db.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

After running, no data is inserting into the database. Any help where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use Spring Data?

Comment: @chrylis i m not able to find error..i m inserting just spring data only

Comment: What is the primary key? and what is the generation strategy for it?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see the transaction isn't getting comitted or opened for that matter. You're probably use to mysql's autocommit being on by default. Either handle the transaction start/commit/rollback in code or turn on autocommit.  I don't suggest autocommit unless you have a good reason and understand the implications.